# Nginx как фронтенд apache 502 bad gateway

Tags: apache, nginx, сервер

Скрипт, при простое, через 25 секунд выдает, 502 bad gateway  ошибку. Если не происходит никакого вывода или другого действия, например простой цикл.

В nginx proxy_read_timeout proxy_connect_timeout стоит 300.

Как мне увеличить время задержки этой? Чтобы не выбрасывало 502 а ждало выполнения скрипта.

Или это на руткод?

Comment: Скрипт на php?

Comment: на php , да

Comment: 502 или 504 ? Потому что 504 - это по таймауту, а 502 - скорее всего не туда проксирует и говорит что веб-вервер не найден.

Comment: да нет 502, может это и не по таймауту но проксирует он точно туда, и веб-сервер, конечно, найден.

Comment: Насколько помню - 502 выдается если от сервера не был получен ответ.

См. [wikipedia](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#502)

Прокси здесь как бы не при делах - это ответ с апача плохой отдается, т.е. смотрите его логи - скорее всего в настройках апача стоит маленькое время выполнения скрипта, либо ошибка в самом скрипте.

Т.е. рыть там, а не в nginx надо

Comment: @BOPOH, если выполнять скрипт напрямую через апач, никаких ошибок нету, execution_time стоит довольно большой. Я читал про ошибку.

Comment: Покажите конфиги. Говорю же что нжинкс или не туда проксирует.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Nginx как фронтенд apache 502 bad gateway](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/346993/nginx-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b4-apache-502-bad-gateway)

Answer (score 0):

[Дебаг лог](http://ruhighload.com/post/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8+error_log+%D0%B8+access_log+%D0%B2+Nginx#debug_log) позволит ответить, какова причина 502 ошибки. Но ее быть не должно, если проблема с долгим временем ответа.