# Nginx как фронтенд apache 502 bad gateway

Tags: apache, nginx, сервер

Скрипт, при простое, через 25 секунд выдает, 502 bad gateway  ошибку. Если не происходит никакого вывода или другого действия, например простой цикл.

В nginx proxy_read_timeout proxy_connect_timeout стоит 300.

Как мне увеличить время задержки этой? Чтобы не выбрасывало 502 а ждало выполнения скрипта.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте error_log nginx'a - куда он именно ломится и что получает. [Debug режим](http://ruhighload.com/post/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8+error_log+%D0%B8+access_log+%D0%B2+Nginx#debug_log) error_log поможет.

Answer (score 0):

У вас в php.conf max_execution_time соответствует ?!

Comment: max_execution_time в htaccess переопределяется для скрипта. А в php.ini стоит 10.

Comment: А на прямую через апач, норм?

Comment: Напрямую через апач все норм, где же эта настройка? Я уже знаю что я ее не смогу поменять ибо впс, но где её найти? Или проставить...

Comment: proxy_connect_timeout -  This directive assigns a timeout for the connection to the upstream server. It is necessary to keep in mind that this time out cannot be more than 75 seconds.

Comment: а там почему-то 300 стоит но больше пишут 75 не может быть, а сбрасывается страница вообще после 25 секунд, я не понимаю?

Comment: Пиши в личку.